# How to catch when project is closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, redmine, after-save

Redmine's model Project has a method

```
  def close
    self_and_descendants.status(STATUS_ACTIVE).update_all :status => STATUS_CLOSED
  end
```

In this method updating with `update_all` means that when projects are closed callback `after_save` is not called.

How do you catch (through model) when a project is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 allows to update records with callbacks and validations:

```
self_and_descendants.status(STATUS_ACTIVE).update(status: STATUS_CLOSED)
```

For Rails 4 and below you can trigger callbacks by updating records in batches:

```
self_and_descendants.status(STATUS_ACTIVE).find_each { |record| record.update_attributes(status: STATUS_CLOSED) }
```

Comment: Yes, but I would like not to change the original method `close`.

Comment: @Willmore Please clarify: You noticed your code has an issue, but you do not want to fix that issue in your code? The documentation of `update_all` clearly says that it will not call validations or callbacks. If you depend on callbacks then you have to use another method.

Comment: @spickermann It is Redmine's model Project that is defined in app/models/project.rb.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the original method in place you could add a plugin patching the close function for you (with the code that Rustik proposed above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48684242/5961910).